# Converting data from one row, to many to create product SKUs

Tags: excel, vba, macos, excel-formula

I have many rows of product data for an ecommerce store, with sizes and colors etc. I need each variation to be on its own row so I can upload all these. I need some kind of Excel formula or VBA to do this I think.

```
Title            Size
Ladies Dress    S,M,L,XL,XXL
Men's Trousers  S,M,L,XL,XXL
```

Required data:

```
Title           Size
Ladies Dress    S
Ladies Dress    M
Ladies Dress    L
Ladies Dress    XL
Ladies Dress    XXL
Men's Trousers  S
Men's Trousers  M
Men's Trousers  L
Men's Trousers  XL
Men's Trousers  XXL
```

I have placed 2 sample rows on a Google Spreadsheet just so I can share this.

[Sample](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16KRHeapKNq2CtMyNfdo-RzqX9k1bOu_rqOTzdVXdRh4/edit?usp=sharing#null)

Comment: A q similar to this has been asked before, do a search on here....

Comment: What version of Excel do you have?

Comment: Mac, Version 16.14.1

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would write a sub for a PC; I'll try to keep the function calls as generic and cross-platform as possible.

```
Option Explicit

Sub sizeExpansion()
    Dim i As Long, szs As Variant

    With Worksheets("sheet1")
        For i = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
            szs = Split(.Cells(i, "B").Value2, ",")
            If CBool(UBound(szs)) Then
                .Cells(i, "A").Resize(UBound(szs), 1).EntireRow.Insert
                .Cells(i, "A").Resize(UBound(szs) + 1, 1) = .Cells(UBound(szs) + i, "A").Value2
                .Cells(i, "B").Resize(UBound(szs) + 1, 1) = Application.Transpose(szs)
            End If
        Next i
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: This is great, but, how do I add another column to this, as I also have colour? DATA NOW  
  
Title                  Size                 Colours
Ladies Dress  S,M,L,XL,XXL Blue, Black, Red
Men's Trousers S,M,L,XL,XXL Brown, Yellow, Orange

Comment: I have tried adapting the code myself, but am unable to. I am very grateful for your help. In this particular case, I had no idea even where to start. I was going to write that on the original post, but learnt a long time ago that less is more on these forums. Look at my other questions and you'll see I always try first. Again, thanks for your help.

Comment: Why don't you start a new question with new sample data and include your effort to adjust the above code along with an explanation of what is going wrong?

Comment: The reason I didn't ask the original question including other fields is I wanted to keep it simple and thought I'd be able to adapt the code from anyone who was kind enough to get me started. Yes, I will do as you suggest. Thank you.